# Why doesn't TextBox1_Click doesn't work while trying to make a click event on a text?

Tags: c#, windows

Basically I want a textbox to open browser but it doesn't work:

```cs
private void TextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Visible = true;
    button3.Visible = true;
    textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Purple;
}
```

Comment: Which part of that code are you expecting to trigger a browser to open?

Comment: Did you associate the event handler (your code) with event Click? What kind of UI technology are you using? WinForms? ASP.NET? WPF?

Comment: @Steve im using WinForms

Comment: @GabrielLuci i press the text and it shows the browser

Comment: @alex12 please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to write a good question. Writing good questions will get you better answers and fewer downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments are hinting, it's not really clear what you're asking.

WebBrowser is a control element on WinForms which you can make visible, as you're doing correctly.

If however you're trying to open an actual browser, you should open it as so:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore.exe");
```